# Open PowerShell here in background directory

Tags: powershell, registry, regedit, registrykey

I have been trying to create some registry keys to open PowerShell as you would Command Prompt in explorer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd>.

I have the context key created here:

[image: <code>HKLM\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell</code>]

but the value I put here:

[image: <code>HKLM\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command</code>]

returns an error when I click `Open PowerShell here`

[image: "Open PowerShell here" context menu]
[image: Error message: "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel."]

I've tried a few string values now but still with similar results. Has anyone accomplished this using the background directory key and if so how did you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `%V` instead of `%1`.

Change the Default value like so:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoExit "cd '%V'"
```